# How to use a pointer to edit array in the main through called function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, prng

I'm trying to use a random number generator function I wrote myself, but I want to call the rng in the main function and have it save the numbers generated into two arrays in the main.  I assume I have to pass some sort of pointer into rng(); to have it edit the arrays in the main?  How to actually format that pointer?  Not allowed to use strings or global arrays...

so I want to put a pointer in place of r[i] so that the function edits the array in the main instead of the array in the function.

```
do{
printf("\nthis is the row number\n\n");
for ( i = 0; i < 11; i++){
 r[i] = rand()%8;
 printf("%d\n", r[i]);
}

printf("\nthis is the column number\n\n");
for ( i = 0; i < 11; i++){
c[i] = rand()%8;
printf("%d\n", c[i]);
}
```

And I want this bit above to save the random numbers it makes to row[] and the second bit to column[] in the main.

```
int main (){
int row[11];
int column[11];
rng();
```

The entire code is shown below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "time.h"
int * rng( ){
int x;
int *t;
x=1;
t=&x;
int y;
int *g;
y=1;
g=&y;
static int  r[11];
static int  c[11];
int i;
int j;
srand(time( NULL ) );

do{
printf("\nthis is the row number\n\n");
for ( i = 0; i < 11; i++){
r[i] = rand()%8;
printf("%d\n", r[i]);
}

printf("\nthis is the column number\n\n");
for ( i = 0; i < 11; i++){
c[i] = rand()%8;
printf("%d\n", c[i]);
}

for (i=0; i<11; i++){
for(j= i+1 ;j<11;j++){
if ((r[i]+1)*(r[i]+1)*(c[i]+1)==(r[j]+1)*(r[j]+1)*(c[j]+1)){
printf("\nOops duplicate number, recalculating\n");
*t=2;
*g=2;
printf("%i", *t);
printf("%i", *g);

}
if (((r[0]+1)*(r[0]+1)*(c[0]+1)!=(r[1]+1)*(r[1]+1)*(c[1]+1))&&
((r[0]+1)*(r[0]+1)*(c[0]+1)!=(r[2]+1)*(r[2]+1)*(c[2]+1))&&
((r[0]+1)*(r[0]+1)*(c[0]+1)!=(r[3]+1)*(r[3]+1)*(c[3]+1))&&
((r[0]+1)*(r[0]+1)*(c[0]+1)!=(r[4]+1)*(r[4]+1)*(c[4]+1))&&
((r[0]+1)*(r[0]+1)*(c[0]+1)!=(r[5]+1)*(r[5]+1)*(c[5]+1))&& 
((r[0]+1)*(r[0]+1)*(c[0]+1)!=(r[6]+1)*(r[6]+1)*(c[6]+1))&&
((r[0]+1)*(r[0]+1)*(c[0]+1)!=(r[7]+1)*(r[7]+1)*(c[7]+1))&&
((r[0]+1)*(r[0]+1)*(c[0]+1)!=(r[8]+1)*(r[8]+1)*(c[8]+1))&&
((r[0]+1)*(r[0]+1)*(c[0]+1)!=(r[9]+1)*(r[9]+1)*(c[9]+1))&&
((r[0]+1)*(r[0]+1)*(c[0]+1)!=(r[10]+1)*(r[10]+1)*(c[10]+1))&&

((r[1]+1)*(r[1]+1)*(c[1]+1)!=(r[2]+1)*(r[2]+1)*(c[2]+1))&&
((r[1]+1)*(r[1]+1)*(c[1]+1)!=(r[3]+1)*(r[3]+1)*(c[3]+1))&&
((r[1]+1)*(r[1]+1)*(c[1]+1)!=(r[4]+1)*(r[4]+1)*(c[4]+1))&&
((r[1]+1)*(r[1]+1)*(c[1]+1)!=(r[5]+1)*(r[5]+1)*(c[5]+1))&&
((r[1]+1)*(r[1]+1)*(c[1]+1)!=(r[6]+1)*(r[6]+1)*(c[6]+1))&&
((r[1]+1)*(r[1]+1)*(c[1]+1)!=(r[7]+1)*(r[7]+1)*(c[7]+1))&&
((r[1]+1)*(r[1]+1)*(c[1]+1)!=(r[8]+1)*(r[8]+1)*(c[8]+1))&&
((r[1]+1)*(r[1]+1)*(c[1]+1)!=(r[9]+1)*(r[9]+1)*(c[9]+1))&&
((r[1]+1)*(r[1]+1)*(c[1]+1)!=(r[10]+1)*(r[10]+1)*(c[10]+1))&&

((r[2]+1)*(r[2]+1)*(c[2]+1)!=(r[3]+1)*(r[3]+1)*(c[3]+1))&&
((r[2]+1)*(r[2]+1)*(c[2]+1)!=(r[4]+1)*(r[4]+1)*(c[4]+1))&&
((r[2]+1)*(r[2]+1)*(c[2]+1)!=(r[5]+1)*(r[5]+1)*(c[5]+1))&&
((r[2]+1)*(r[2]+1)*(c[2]+1)!=(r[6]+1)*(r[6]+1)*(c[6]+1))&&
((r[2]+1)*(r[2]+1)*(c[2]+1)!=(r[7]+1)*(r[7]+1)*(c[7]+1))&&
((r[2]+1)*(r[2]+1)*(c[2]+1)!=(r[8]+1)*(r[8]+1)*(c[8]+1))&&
((r[2]+1)*(r[2]+1)*(c[2]+1)!=(r[9]+1)*(r[9]+1)*(c[9]+1))&&
((r[2]+1)*(r[2]+1)*(c[2]+1)!=(r[10]+1)*(r[10]+1)*(c[10]+1))&&

((r[3]+1)*(r[3]+1)*(c[3]+1)!=(r[4]+1)*(r[4]+1)*(c[4]+1))&&
((r[3]+1)*(r[3]+1)*(c[3]+1)!=(r[5]+1)*(r[5]+1)*(c[5]+1))&&
((r[3]+1)*(r[3]+1)*(c[3]+1)!=(r[6]+1)*(r[6]+1)*(c[6]+1))&&
((r[3]+1)*(r[3]+1)*(c[3]+1)!=(r[7]+1)*(r[7]+1)*(c[7]+1))&&
((r[3]+1)*(r[3]+1)*(c[3]+1)!=(r[8]+1)*(r[8]+1)*(c[8]+1))&&
((r[3]+1)*(r[3]+1)*(c[3]+1)!=(r[9]+1)*(r[9]+1)*(c[9]+1))&&
((r[3]+1)*(r[3]+1)*(c[3]+1)!=(r[10]+1)*(r[10]+1)*(c[10]+1))&&

((r[4]+1)*(r[4]+1)*(c[4]+1)!=(r[5]+1)*(r[5]+1)*(c[5]+1))&&
((r[4]+1)*(r[4]+1)*(c[4]+1)!=(r[6]+1)*(r[6]+1)*(c[6]+1))&&
((r[4]+1)*(r[4]+1)*(c[4]+1)!=(r[7]+1)*(r[7]+1)*(c[7]+1))&&
((r[4]+1)*(r[4]+1)*(c[4]+1)!=(r[8]+1)*(r[8]+1)*(c[8]+1))&&
((r[4]+1)*(r[4]+1)*(c[4]+1)!=(r[9]+1)*(r[9]+1)*(c[9]+1))&&
((r[4]+1)*(r[4]+1)*(c[4]+1)!=(r[10]+1)*(r[10]+1)*(c[10]+1))&&

((r[5]+1)*(r[5]+1)*(c[5]+1)!=(r[6]+1)*(r[6]+1)*(c[6]+1))&&
((r[5]+1)*(r[5]+1)*(c[5]+1)!=(r[7]+1)*(r[7]+1)*(c[7]+1))&&
((r[5]+1)*(r[5]+1)*(c[5]+1)!=(r[8]+1)*(r[8]+1)*(c[8]+1))&&
((r[5]+1)*(r[5]+1)*(c[5]+1)!=(r[9]+1)*(r[9]+1)*(c[9]+1))&&
((r[5]+1)*(r[5]+1)*(c[5]+1)!=(r[10]+1)*(r[10]+1)*(c[10]+1))&&

((r[6]+1)*(r[6]+1)*(c[6]+1)!=(r[7]+1)*(r[7]+1)*(c[7]+1))&&
((r[6]+1)*(r[6]+1)*(c[6]+1)!=(r[8]+1)*(r[8]+1)*(c[8]+1))&&
((r[6]+1)*(r[6]+1)*(c[6]+1)!=(r[9]+1)*(r[9]+1)*(c[9]+1))&&
((r[6]+1)*(r[6]+1)*(c[6]+1)!=(r[10]+1)*(r[10]+1)*(c[10]+1))&&

((r[7]+1)*(r[7]+1)*(c[7]+1)!=(r[8]+1)*(r[8]+1)*(c[8]+1))&&
((r[7]+1)*(r[7]+1)*(c[7]+1)!=(r[9]+1)*(r[9]+1)*(c[9]+1))&&
((r[7]+1)*(r[7]+1)*(c[7]+1)!=(r[10]+1)*(r[10]+1)*(c[10]+1))&&

((r[8]+1)*(r[8]+1)*(c[8]+1)!=(r[9]+1)*(r[9]+1)*(c[9]+1))&&
((r[8]+1)*(r[8]+1)*(c[8]+1)!=(r[10]+1)*(r[10]+1)*(c[10]+1))&&

((r[9]+1)*(r[9]+1)*(c[9]+1)!=(r[10]+1)*(r[10]+1)*(c[10]+1))){
printf("\nno errors\n");
*t=2;
*g=1;
printf("%i", *t);
printf("%i", *g);
break;
}
}
}
}while(*t==*g);

}




int main (){

int map[8][8];
int row[11];
int column[11];
//int *p;
int i;
// p = row[];
rng(row, column);
```

Comment: An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.

Comment: Agreed, I'm sorry that I don't have the time to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void rng(int *r, int *c){
    ...
    do{
        printf("\nthis is the row number\n\n");
        for ( i = 0; i < 11; i++){
            r[i] = rand()%8;
            printf("%d\n", r[i]);
        }

        printf("\nthis is the column number\n\n");
        for ( i = 0; i < 11; i++){
            c[i] = rand()%8;
            printf("%d\n", c[i]);
        }
    ...

int main (){
    int row[11];
    int column[11];
    rng(row, column);
    ...
```

Comment: I think this might fix my problem.  Can you explain how this works so I can make my own later?  are *r and *c pointers to row[] and column[] in the main?

Comment: @TylerLively `row` meant `&row[0]`. Also `void rng(int *r, int *c){` can be written as `void rng(int r[], int c[]){`. They have the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of declaring r and c locally in your rng() function, just pass row and column to rng(row, column) by reference.

```
rng (int* row, int* column){

}
```

Comment: that's what I'm trying to do, my question is how to actually do that, because whenever I try to pass row[] into rng() it says its not defined in rng or something.  That seems like the best way to do it though.

Comment: its gross but sure.  Thanks for the help, I'm really knew to c.